# Lebesgue integral of a bounded measurable function over a measurable subset of a measurable set of finite measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f$ be a bounded measurable function on a set $E$ of finite measure. For a measurable subset $A$ of $E$, show that $\int_A f=\int_E f\cdot\chi_A$, where $\chi_A$ is a characteristic function on $A$ and $\int_A f$ is the Lebesgue integral of $f$ on $A$.

How am I going to establish this? Help please. Thanks

Comment: This exact question was already asked within the last 8 hours (and quite probably before that, too).

Comment: What is the question? This statement just defines $\int_A f$.

Comment: I think this is a definition type problem you can work out yourself. I would encourage you to look up the definition of Lesbegue integral on measure space and see why they are equal.

Comment: Duplicate of [Bounded measurable function and integral with charcteristic function](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/285655) and [Restriction of a Lebesgue integral to a subset of a measurable set.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/235481)